# Protocols containing redeclared properties

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have been trying to find an answer to understand the "under the hook" or "technicalities" on whether or not the following code should be or not be avoided:

```
protocol Member {
    var id: String: { get }
    var name: String { get }
}

protocol RegularMember: Member {
    var name: String { get }
    ...
}
```

**RegularMember** declares the same property **name** that **Member** also declares.

I have had this question always in my head and always assumed that it was bad practice but never got further than that.

Does anyone have different thoughts?

Comment: it inherited the name property from Member protocol.

Comment: There are probably better things that the Swift team should be doing...

Comment: I was trying to get some opinions. But if the question is so awful to downvote then I will close it...

Comment: Asking for opinions is forbidden on Stack Overflow. But it isn't a matter of opinion; it's written into the syntax rules that repeating the adopted requirements is okay.

Answer (score 2):

> However, Xcode is not showing neither a warning nor an error.

Because it isn't wrong for protocol B that conforms to protocol A to repeat requirements from protocol A. Quite the contrary! It doesn't change the meaning of anything, and in fact, it's good practice stylistically because it can make your code more readable; the Swift Standard Library does it a lot.